# How to use exceptions reasonably in business logic?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

When I use Springboot to write code, there are Controller layer, Service layer and Repository layer. In the Service layer, I need to verify whether multiple business conditions are correct. If they are correct, I will continue to execute and return success. But if the business condition verification fails and the condition is not met, should I throw an exception to the Controller layer or return a null value.

1. If I throw an exception, the Controller layer can get the message that the Service execution failed and sent it to the front end. But this approach may bring performance problems
2. If I return a null value, then the Controller layer cannot know why the Service failed to execute

For example

```
Controller.java 

@RestController
public class Controller{
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String testController(){
        service.business();
    }
}
```

```
Service.java 

public class Service{
    public String business(){
        if(checkConditions_1() == false){
            // Should I throw an exception or return null
            ......
        }    
        if(checkConditions_2() == false){
            // Should I throw an exception or return null
            ......
        }
        if(checkConditions_3() == false){
            // Should I throw an exception or return null
            ......
        }    
        ......
        return success;
    }
}
```

1. How should exceptions be used reasonably in business logic?
2. Is there a code specification or related books?

Comment: 3) Log a message and return null?  4) ... 5) profit

Comment: throw exception and catch it in RestControllerAdvice

Comment: Since its a business logic related exception, you need to know what is the behavior of the application in case of such an exception. Based upon this your application handles it (this might involve throwing a business exception and handling it 'appropriately'). How Spring handles or Spring applications handle such exceptions is another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was you, I would use this approach where I create one ApiResponse class, and inside this, I create all things which I want to show on frontend like status, and message as per requirement these things make your error more readable and understandable if someone encounters the error while using exception is a costly thing like if there is any bug or any issue exception handling is going to hide those things and also we can't predict in which way our code going to perform or there will be the impact on your code performance when we are using exception there are some other factors but I think I made my point clear to you so until or unless if it is not necessary then don't use exceptions

```
//----------here is an example----------------//
//checkpoint to check username, email and phone number of coaching if same 
  stop or move forward
public ResponseEntity<Object> checkCoachingDetails(AddCoachingRequest 
                                                   addCoachingRequest)
{
    Coaching coachingExistByUsername = 
      coachingRepository.findByUsername(addCoachingRequest.getUsername());
    Coaching coachingExistByEmail = 
      coachingRepository.findByEmail(addCoachingRequest.getEmail());
    Coaching coachingExistByPhoneNum = 
 coachingRepository.findByPhoneNumber(addCoachingRequest.getPhoneNumber());

    if(coachingExistByUsername != null && coachingExistByEmail != null && 
       coachingExistByPhoneNum != null)
    {
    //earlier i was throwing exception if i was not able to find the 
      coaching by username, email or phone number
    //throw new UserAlreadyExistException("Username and/or Email and/or 
          Mobile number already in use!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);   


     //now i used this approach here
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ApiResponse(false, 
    "Username and/or Email and/or Mobile number already in use!")); 
    }  
}

//---this is my ApiResponse class----//
  public class ApiResponse 
  {
     private Boolean status;
     private String message;
  }


//------this is my custom exception class------//
  public class UserAlreadyExistException extends RuntimeException
  {
    public UserAlreadyExistException(String message, HttpStatus badRequest) 
    {
    
    } 
   }
```

let me know if anywhere my point is not clear or understandable

Comment: Thank you, this method is really useful, it can solve my problem, I will encapsulate a return object, which includes the business data and abnormal status to be returned, etc.

Comment: Welcome! If you find my answer helpful, I would appreciate an upvote.